# Is the cardinality of this well-ordered set $\aleph_0$?

Tags: set-theory

Given a well ordered set $S$, any element $a\in S$ except the least element of $S$ has a unique predecessor, is the cardinal of $S$ equal to $\aleph_0$?

Comment: I have modified my question.

Comment: Any well ordered set is order isomorphic to a ordinal.......

Comment: Consider the well-ordered set $S=\{0,1,2,3\},$ ordered so that $0\lt1\lt2\lt3.$ The smallest element, $0,$ has no predecessors. The next smallest element, $1,$ has a unique predecessor, namely $0.$ The next smallest element, $2,$ has two predecessors, $0$ and $1.$ The next element, $3,$ has three predecessors, $0,\ 1,$ and $2.$ If each element of a well-ordered set has at most one predecessor, then the cardinality is at most $2.$

Comment: Perhaps, by "predecessor", you meant *immediate* predecessor? But then there would be no need to say "unique", an element of a totally ordered set can't have more than one immediate predecessor.

Comment: @bof I think (s)he means that every element *has* an immediate predecessor. Of course, in any finite ordinal every element also has an immediate predecessor. But assuming the ordinal is infinite it will have to be countable (and specifically order isomorphic to the natural numbers). Any other ordinal will have a limit element without predecessors because it contains $\omega$ as initial segment.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that you want each element of $S$ to have an *immediate* predecessor, and that you want $S$ to be infinite, then yes. To show this, we need to construct a bijection with $\omega$; define $f:\omega \to S$ inductively by setting $f(0)$ to be the least element of $S$ and $f(n + 1)$ to be the least element of $S$ greater than $f(n)$. This is clearly injective, so it remains to show that it's surjective.

Suppose $a \in S$ is not in the range of $f$. Then we can define a new function $g:\omega \to S$ by taking $g(0) = a$ and $g(n+1)$ to be the immediate predecessor of $g(n)$ in $S$. By induction, $g(n)$ is not in the range of $f$ for any $n$, so in particular $g(n)$ is not the least element of $S$, and so the necessary predecessors exist. But then the range of $g$ is a subset of $S$ with no least element, contradicting the assumption that $S$ is well-ordered. So no such $a$ exists, so $f$ is a bijection.

As a side note, $f$ is actually an order-isomorphism - $f(n) < f(m)$ whenever $n < m$. So not only does $S$ have cardinality $\aleph_0$, it has the smallest possible order type of that cardinality.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma No, in $\omega + 1$ the last element has no immediate predecessor. The *least* element is an exception.

Comment: I read last instead of least, sorry.